# Is there a way to determine if a ray is coming from a volume?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, shaders, volumetrics

I am trying to create a light that only illuminates volume scatters.

The *input > light path* node has "*is X ray*" outputs for all the various types of rays coming off a surface.  However I'd like something like an *is volume ray* output to tell if a ray is coming from a volume.  Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible atm.. :/

Comment: This is a great question, and although an "Is Volume Ray" feature would be very handy, I'm wondering - could you use the "Is X Ray" output to determine that it is not a surface output (and therefor presumably a volume output) as a solution for your particular use case?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I am not sure about using some sort of 'Is Volume Ray' value to make a light source only illuminate a volume, but if you simply want a lamp/meshlight to only illuminate a volume scatter material, in the ray visibility settings of that light, you can leave only the 'Volume Scatter' ticked and the rest unticked:

[image]

Keep in mind that the light source may still end up illuminating the scene due to multiple volume bounces and the density of the volume.

Here is a simple scene with a point lamp directly above suzanne with a volume scatter material and a maximum of 32 volume bounces. The ray visibility is of the lamp directly above suzanne.

[image]

Here is the same scene except with only the 'Volume Scatter' ticked for the point lamp.

[image]

Here is the same scene with only 8 volume bounces. You can see how there is more light exiting suzanne with 32 volume bounces than with 8, though it is a very small difference.

[image]