# Making Emission Object Invisible with Volume Scatter

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, light, volumetrics

I am desperately trying to animate a 'tour' through an interior space and am having trouble getting enough light in the space. I have added emission to mesh shapes to light the various areas and even though i turned off their visibility to the camera they are still visible to some extent. I believe this is doe to the fact that I have Volume scatter on the main light source. I have tried enabling/disabling VS in the Cycles Setting under the Object button but it does not help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I think when you just make them invisible for the camera, it will still render them, but if you say, it should not be rendered, it won't render the light too.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-ray-is-coming-from-a-volume.

Comment: Any particular reason you have volume scattering on the light source?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the object tab under cycle setings, ray visibility and deselect the camera. It should not be rendered anymore.
You may have to set the surface to emission, not the volume.

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately both of your suggestions are currently the case.